# Cant add attributes to buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

so I'm working with creating an html-based game. I've been testing and I just cant figure one thing out. This is my code:

```html
<button onclick="test()">
Click Me!
</button>
<script>
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
```

So this code does work. However, the button added does not do anything but change color when clicked. How can I make it so the button added runs a function?

**EDIT:** After the suggestions, I have this code:

```html
<button onclick="test()">
Click Me!
</button>
<script>
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.onclick = test();
}
</script>
```

And it creates a large amount of buttons when the first one is clicked.

**EDIT 2:** I got it to work now.

```html
<button onclick="test()">
Click Me!
</button>
<script>
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.onclick = function(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
}
</script>
```

Thanks for the help everyone! :)

**EDIT 3:** ...and another thing doesn't work. I updated the code to:

```html
<button onclick="test()">
Click Me!
</button>
<script>
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Click Me!")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.onclick = function(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Click Me!")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.onclick = test()
}
}
</script>
```

But when I click the button created from the original button, it creates 2 instead of just 1, which is what I want. In addition, the first of the two does nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: add a click event to the button...

Comment: @DimensionalDrift Check out my answer and fiddle. If you have questions, let me know

Comment: Perhaps your question could be improved by removing your solution, and creating an answer for it, after all this is a `Question` =] you can still leave the accepted answer as it is, your self answer answer needn't be accepted to be helpful to people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an onclick function to the button

e.g

```
function myFunction() {
 // onclick stuff
}

element.onclick = myFunction; // Assigned
```

[UPDATE]

to make it easier I've created a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/33h3bgxc/1/

Comment: How do I add this to the button? Or do I just need to place it in the function?

Comment: btn.onclick = myFunction;

Comment: Okay, so how do I get it to run a different function?

Comment: well.. I can't create the system for you. to run a different function you will need to create the logic for that.

Comment: but just to help you with a simple example I have updated the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/33h3bgxc/2/
this is a really simple example.

Comment: @DimensionalDrift if my answer helped you, could you mark as answer so others can be helped too?

Comment: Can you check my new edits and try and figure out the problems?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your confusion is due to the fact that your dynamically adding elements (in this case, buttons) and then wanting to access said elements (buttons).

The easiest way to name these new elements is to first assign the statement that creates them,

```
document.createElement("BUTTON");
```

to a variable, which you actually did do!

```
btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
```

So, keep in mind that you can do stuff with that variable you created, like giving it a class or ID name to access.

```
btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-class');
```

Now you can assign any styling elements from your CSS with class name `btn-class` or whatever else you may desire to choose.

Here's a JSFiddle that shows that: https://jsfiddle.net/dg1amubr/4/

Comment: Can you look at my new problem please?

Comment: @DimensionalDrift Are you talking about Edit 3?

Comment: @DimensionalDrift Please explain what you see it doing and what you expect it to do, so that I may assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener` to attach an event with new button. Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var name = document.createTextNode("Button");
btn.id = "newButton"
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
var _getNewButton = document.getElementById('newButton');
_getNewButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
alert('New Button');
})
}
// You can also directly attach addEventListener without going via id.
// btn.addEventListener('click',function(){ ..})
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5c0xha0/10/)

Comment: why do you have the {} after the ('click",function()?

Comment: that is how a function is defined

Comment: So that section is a new function?

Comment: Yes it is function that will be executed on clicking of the button. Instead of that you can also pass a call back function

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an event handler to that button.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
   console.log('I was clicked');
});
```

```js
function test() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
  var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
  btn.appendChild(name);
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert('I was clicked');
  });
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">
  Click Me!
</button>
```

Comment: what is the function(event) part? I just want it to run the function test() for now until I can finish my code.

Comment: Thats the function that will get called when you click the button, `addEventListener(string eventName, function callback)` is the signature. So you can just write `btn.addEventListener('click', test);` to pass it your `test` function

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to use something like

```
btn.addEventListener('click',callback_function)
```

?