# change attributes on button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to do a project in which I need to change attributes on a button. I have no code for you, but I still need help. Is there any way I can change a button that's already there so that the onclick attribute runs a different function from before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the answers have been helpful. Thank you all.

Comment: You need to accept the most useful answer.

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question with code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577827/cant-add-attributes-to-buttons

Answer (score 1):

I feel like all the answers so far miss the main point. Since you don't have any code examples, I'm guessing you'll find it hard to extrapolate out what everyone is saying.

So, one button, which when clicked, changes to another method, and when clicked again, changes back. I'm using the `onclick` attribute for simplicity, but as others have shown, using JavaScript `.onclick` or `addEventListener` is a better choice.

```js
function function1(e) {
  // Show where we're at
  alert("function1 is running");

  // Get which button was clicked from the event that is passed in, and set its onclick event
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("onclick", "function2(event)");
}


function function2(e) {
  // Show where we're at
  alert("function2 is running");

  // Get which button was clicked from the event that is passed in, and set its onclick event
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("onclick", "function1(event)");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="function1(event)">Click Me!</button>
```

You can of course change what `function1` and `function2` do, and add more changes (e.g. function 3 and 4), add logic for when to change, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

use `.onclick = function_name;`

Demo :

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = fun2;

function fun1() {
  alert('I am from Function 1');
}

function fun2() {
  alert('I am from Function 2');
}
```

```html
<button id='myButton' onclick='fun1()'>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There's only one thing to keep in mind:

- An event on which you want the change to happen

Once you have identified that event, just bind it with JQuery's `.attr()` function to change any attribute.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Javascript Events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery like:

```
 $("mybtn").click(function(){
$("#mybtn").attr({
    "onclick" : "anotherFunction()",
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ga3k7ssp/1/

I set a variable to 0 and this function for button 1:

```
bt1.onclick = function(){
  i++;
  myPar.innerHTML = i; 
};
```

It increases the variable and displays the number.

But, clicking on button 2, it changes button 1 function:

```
bt1.onclick = function(){
  i--;
  myPar.innerHTML = i;
};
```

Now button 1 decreases the variable.

This other fiddle is similar, but using radio buttons, to show that you can set the original function of button 1 back: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/8gbLq355/1/